Error: "Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21" in Flutter app on Android
So I am working on flutter and there was this error.
Execution failed for task ':photo_manager:compileDebugKotlin'.\ Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':photo_manager:compileDebugKotlin'.\ Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.\ Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

I am using photomanager framework in Flutter labybug patch 2.
What are the best setting for gradle for getting permissions?

I want to clarify this, did you follow this way of adding the photo_manager package, with this approach (Recommend) Run flutter pub add photo_manager?

I'd like to be familiar with your issue since I have no idea how to reproduce it. Can you tell me what happened next to your issue?

You need to migrate to the latest development setup; you may follow this configuration for that matter:
Make sure you are using Java 17 or Java 21 JDK. Here's the reference for it.
To verify which Java JDK you're using, execute these commands in your IDE terminal:
java --version

If you manually installed it:
For Java 17 JDK
flutter config --jdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"

For Java 21 JDK
flutter config --jdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21"

Note: To tell Flutter compiler to use this particular installed JDK, of course, don't forget to change your PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables.
Now, you should have these configurations of your project:
In android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

(if you prefer to use a CLI) To set it into that specific distributionUrl, execute this command in your android directory:
PS C:\path_to_your_project\android>./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.3 --distribution-type all

In your app\build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.my_project"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.my_project"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = 23 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

In your settings.gradle file:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.4" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false
}

include ":app"

After following the configurations above, execute these commands in your terminal:
flutter pub get
flutter pub clean
flutter pub cache repair

Note: flutter pub cache repair is optional.
If you're using Android Studio, perform/select this in your IDE:
File > Invalidate Caches...
Now rebuild your project again. Let me know what happened next.
Personal advice: according to its official documentation, you need to have an updated development setup.
PS: Make sure you thoroughly read the photo_manager package's official documentation if you have platform-specific concerns.
Edit
You can also use Android Gradle plugin 8.7.
I hope it helps!

it worked it seems the minSdk needed was needed to be above 21.

I'm glad to hear (know) that from you. Keep up the good work!
